# prettyPhoto pp_gallery doesn't show up on large amout of pics

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I've just noticed that great feature of prettyPhoto - mini-thumbnail doensn't show up on gallery which contains large amout of pictures i.e. 80 imgs. Then .pp_gllery just disapper - any suggestions how to fix this?

PrettyPhoto 3.1.5, 
jQuery 1.10.2

Or maybe someone know similar lightbox with thumnail and social buttons like prettyPhoto?

jsfiddle.net/FbSs8

Comment: Here is jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/FbSs8/ please remove about half of photos from html and then thumbnail will appear

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
//Pretty Photo
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    social_tools: false, 
    deeplinking:false,
    overlay_gallery: ture    
});
```